# Ionic native google maps marker issues

Tags: angular, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-markers, ionic3

I am building an ionic 3 app and trying to make the htmlInfoWIndow to show up on a map but without any luck.
I am using the following versions:
 "@ionic-native/google-maps": "4.4.2",     "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.1.1",

```
loadMap() {
    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map', mapOptions);

    // Wait the MAP_READY before using any methods.
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');

        let htmlInfoWindow = new HtmlInfoWindow();

        let html = [
          '<h2>Title here....</h2>'
        ].join("");
        htmlInfoWindow.setContent(html);

        // Now you can use all methods safely.
        this.map.addMarker({
          position: {
            lat: 43.0741904,
            lng: -89.3809802
          }
        })
          .then((marker: Marker) => {
            marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
              .subscribe(() => {
                htmlInfoWindow.open(marker);
                console.log('sad');
              });
          });


      });
  }
```

loadMap() function is initialized on ionicviewenter. The console log is printed out but no info window is appearing on marker click.

Any ideeas what i am doing wrong?
Thanks,
Trix

Comment: Use `ionViewDidLoad()` instead of `ionicViewEnter()`

Comment: Found the issue, the marker div was added but for some reason the visiblity: hidden property was not changed to visibility: visible. After doing this manualy all is oke.

Answer (score 0):

check that (go to diapositive 42)

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vScoho1ensbR4qCI9AIuQN55BZVvK73pAjI7sumDvW3CrxxHnrmpXWUjx2-8CpFibqU1EjLKCRhuthJ/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000

Comment: Yeh that was what i tried in the first place, but the visibility on the htmlinfowindow didnt change so i forced it in css. Now its good.